# Listener for "accent color override" for system tray on windows on Electron

Tags: windows, icons, electron, system-tray

On Windows, the Electron [systemPreferences API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences) lets us listen for `accent-color` changes, as well as checking the existing `accent-color`. However, there is no way (as far as I can tell) to detect when a user has selected the option to `show accent color on the following surfaces` in their color settings (overriding the default system tray color).

[image]

Note: my hope is there is some windows event that we can perhaps listen to which detects the appropriate setting being changed. On the Mac side of things for example, alongside `isDarkMode` detection, we have the following listener to detect theme changes:

`systemPreferences.subscribeNotification('AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification', macThemeDidChange);`

Appreciate all input, thanks.